# How do I determine if an element is in a list?

Tags: python, list

```
thelist = [{'color':'green', 'time':4}, {'color':'red','time':2},{'color':'blue','time':5}]
```

How do I say:

```
If "red" is in thelist and time does not equal 2 for that element (that's we just got from the list):
```

Comment: Is there a difference in speed between "wallacoloo" answer and the list comprehension/pythonic answers?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using [`any()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any) to find out if there is an element satisfying the conditions:

```
>>> any(item['color'] == 'red' and item['time'] != 2  for item in thelist)
False
```

Comment: this is nice! Am I understanding it correctly that the parentheses of the any() are doubling as a generator, so any() evaluates the list comprehension item by item and will return True once it finds an item that satisfies the criteria?

Comment: It's a "generator expression", available in reasonably reason version of python (since 2.4). One could also write `any([...])` to get a classical list comprehension. (see http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/ for more on generator expressions)

Comment: That's the kind of stuff that makes me love Python.

Answer (score 1):

```
def colorRedAndTimeNotEqualTo2(thelist):
    for i in thelist:
        if i["color"] == "red" and i["time"] != 2:
            return True
    return False

print colorRedAndTimeNotEqualTo2([{'color':'green', 'time':4}, {'color':'red','time':2},{'color':'blue','time':5}])
```

for i in thelist iterates through thelist, assigning the current element to i and doing the rest of the code in the block (for each value of i)

Thanks for the catch, Benson.

Comment: beaten to the punch by 30 seconds-- this is exactly what I would do. Except, just to be in the python 3 habit: print(i)

Comment: That's workable, but the use of a for loop means that if there was more than one element with color == red and time != 2 you'd get I printed twice.

Answer (score 0):

You can do most of the list manipulation in a list comprehension.  Here's one that makes a list of times for all elements where the color is red.  Then you can ask if 2 exists in those times.

```
thelist = [{'color':'green', 'time':4}, {'color':'red','time':2},{'color':'blue','time':5}]
reds = ( x['time'] == 2 for x in thelist if x['color'] == red )
if False in reds:
  do_stuff()
```

You can condense that even further by eliminating the variable "reds" like this:

```
thelist = [{'color':'green', 'time':4}, {'color':'red','time':2},{'color':'blue','time':5}]
if False in ( x['time'] == 2 for x in thelist if x['color'] == red ):
  do_stuff()
```

Comment: this requires 2 searches instead of 1 (one to get the element, another to find False). this also needs more ram (the list comprehension could generate a huge result). iterating would be more efficient

Comment: I switched to generator comprehensions rather than list comprehensions, since (as jspcal said) the lists were unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's nothing as elegant as "find" but you can use a list comprehension:

```
matches = [x for x in thelist if x["color"] == "red" and x["time"] != 2]
if len(matches):
    m = matches[0]
    # do something with m
```

However, I find the `[0]` and len() tedious. I often use a for loop with an array slice, such as:

```
matches = [x for x in thelist if x["color"] == "red" and x["time"] != 2]
for m in matches[:1]:
    # do something with m
```

Comment: I was assuming an "at most one" kind of find. If you want all matches, I'd defer to someone else's answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
list = [{'color':'green', 'time':4}, {'color':'red','time':2},{'color':'blue','time':5}]
for i in list:
  if i['color'] == 'red' && i['time'] != 2:
    print i
```

Comment: Perhaps this is too nitpicky, but I recommend you avoid naming things "list", because you may at some point need access to the list constructor and it would be a shame to have overwritten it.

Comment: Python uses "and" instead of "&&"

Answer (score 0):

```
for val in thelist:
    if val['color'] == 'red' and val['time'] != 2:
        #do something here
```

But it doesn't look like that's the right data structure to use.